# how do you center table using css

Tags: css, google-chrome

I have a table in my html that I would like to center on my page. I have the following code. I is perfectly find in ie but not in chrome. Am I doing something wrong?

```
<table align="center">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="zoom_controls"> </div>
            </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Where's your CSS? Be sure your container (for example, the `body` element) has `text-align: center`, and then ensure the table has `margin: 0 auto;`, and it will center in the space.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `align="center"` syntax was deprecated a long time ago. Add `margin:0 auto` to your table:

```
table {
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/PPsuQ/)** (border added for visibility)

Answer (score 0):

Give the table a fixed width, if possible.
Give the table a top- and bottom-margin of 0 (or other if you want to) and a left- and right-margin of auto.

This works with every kind of element with a known width.
You can also use a variable width (em / %).

EDIT: seems like other were typing the same solution as me.

Answer (score -1):

For me what worked is:
margin: auto;
display: inline-block;

Tables

Comment: Welcome to SO, your answer does not add any value to the question and is very similar to the chosen answer already, `inline-block` is not necessary for centering elements.